# Two way binding in Angular is resulting in one way binding

Tags: angular, components, two-way-binding, inputbinding

I am new to Angular and following the video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Es9AaNBJ5Q&list=PLOghUv2IDLKHo0CJkwLcbb1YW0As5fRZd&index=46

But, two way databinding is not working. Initially, the input text has the value
my@abc.com
However, when I change the value and hit enter key, the value still is my@abc.com

Here are all the versions
Angular CLI: 16.1.4
Node: 16.15.1
Package Manager: npm 8.11.0
OS: win32 x64

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { CoursesService } from "./courses.service";

@Component( {
    selector: 'courses',
    template: `
    <input type="text" [value]="email" (keyup.enter)="onKeyEnter()"/>
    `
} )
export class CoursesComponent{
    email:string;
    constructor(service:CoursesService) {
        this.email = "my@abc.com";
    }
    onKeyEnter()
    {
        console.log("My new email id : " , this.email);
    }
};
```

Comment: for two way binding change `[value]="email"` with `[(ngModel)]="email"` in your input field.

Answer (score 1):

> The video is trying to explain how the to-way binding works behind the
> scene by writing a two way binding manually. This way is good to
> teach somebody to build up mental model from scratch. But I would not recommend you try on real applications.
> Though what was the problem I explained about.

The problem are

1. You're not assigning a value to `email` model from `onKeyEnter` function.
2. For doing the same you have to pass the value to `onKeyEnter`
   function by accessing `$event` special object.
3. Also change event to `keyup` only instead of `keyup.enter`

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" [value]="email" (keyup)="onKeyEnter($event.target.value)"/>
```

**TS**

```
onKeyEnter(value: string) {
  this.email = value;
}
```

Okay then gradually for learning you can make use `ngModel` (kind of similar to what you did before)

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="email" (ngModelChange)="email=$event">
```

Above `[]` stands for `Property` binding and `()` event binding.

---

And then you can go further to combine both `[]` and `()` which becomes `[(ngModel)]` and `change` text get removed. So it becomes

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="email" />
```

Other way is to play with two way binding is model driven form which uses `formControl`/`formControlName`.

Don't forget to import the `FormsModule` in your `app.module.ts` imports array.

Comment: but he is using keyup.enter just to print the email value not to pass values

Comment: @DEV yes, thanks a lot for headsup. I updated the answer in a way to accommodate the perspective of OP, I know its very tough when you try wrap your head around these concepts. I hope the above answer really answered both things, what OP referring too vs what he should use.

Answer (score 0):

Try using   [(ngModel)]="value"

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="email" (keyup.enter)="onKeyEnter()"/>
```

> ngModel Creates a FormControl instance from a domain model and binds it to a
> form control element.

[for more ...](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#description)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you did not watch the video till the end in the same video it has the answer for two way binding you need to use `[(ngModel)]` instead of `[value]` directive.

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="email" (keyup.enter)="onKeyEnter()"/>
```

P.S: import `FomsModule` in case if you face this error `Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't know property of 'input'`

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

imports: [ 
           ...
           FormsModule
         ]
```